# I want to delete the characters in the text using the replace() function for python, but only half of them are deleted

Tags: python, text, replace, printing, output

```
minutes = ("<5 Seconds").text.replace("<", "0.").replace("Seconds", "")
print(minutes)
```

**The output i wanted: 0.5**

**output: <5**

how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post what is the text, what are you trying to replace and expected output. Your question is unclear

Comment: ```minutes = "<5 Seconds".replace("<", "0.").replace("Seconds", "")```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
m = '<5 Seconds'
m = m.replace('<', '0.').replace('Seconds', '')
print(m)
```

```
0.5
```